# Animate Branch Growth

Tags: animation

I was trying to create a animated effect on the branch of the "Sapling tree gen" but couldn't animate the respective.So,I would like to know is there a way to animate just the "branch growth" property.If not then can you please give me an idea of how to accomplish the respective? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That can probably be done with animation nodes. Here is a link from the author with additional links in the description https://youtu.be/nCghhlMOwRg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve a simplistic tree growth animation using the *Bevel Factor* property of the curve.

[image: Tree growth]

You might have to separate your tree into several discreet branch levels, and for a proper realistic effect it will probably require a lot of manual work.

Create a Sapling tree, enter *Edit Mode* select the whole main trunk and separate it with <kbd>P</kbd>.

Then select one of the branch tips (radius $0$), <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> *Select Grouped > Radius* then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select all linked vertex. Press <kbd>P</kbd> again to separate that whole branch level.

Repeat for every branch level you wish to animate independently.

[image: Tree Sapling]

You can then animate the individual *Bevel Factor* properties on each curve object to achieve a simplistic growth animation by pressing keyframing the property with <kbd>i</kbd> while hovering it.

Separate into further objects for more detailed growth, for example by height levels, so lower branches can start growing before the upper ones.

[image: Animate Bevel Factor]