# How can I animate something being constructed?

Tags: modeling, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to animate something like a wall being created out of the ground.

Like this, per example:[image]

What I want is to make the ice appear (being stacked and you can see is it forming into a "puddle" like) on the ground first.

Being created like this
[image]

Followed by the walls being pushed out of the ice in order to create the wall.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Those are pretty distinct effects, there is no single simple recipe for that, nor are those trivial to simulate. This question is too broad, try narrowing it down to specific problems. Also see related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73633/animate-branch-growth or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos That helped a lot but it isn't exactly like that.
I would say, imagine a snow storm, the snow will create a little pile. Now that but fast forward.

Comment: You could maybe animate a displacement map on top of a growing object

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'm still learning. 
Could you show me what's that and how to do that?

Comment: Maybe these can get you started https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15036/how-to-animate-the-displacement-of-the-displace-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49199/water-ripples-waves-on-the-surface-of-an-object/49216#49216 You can animated the *Strength* parameter of the modifier.

Comment: Using shape keys and drivers could work

Answer (score 4):

If your "wall", as in the first picture, is "icy" meaning that it should grow from something like "water", another approach could use a reversed fluid animation, maybe:

[image]

You could use better (reverse) "start" shapes, and/or add displacements to final result, and also animate materials/textures to make the  fluid > solid transition modify the final shape, adding more interesting details...

Comment: That helped a lot but not exactly what I'm asking. Making the wall appear was pretty much like you did but my intention is to keep the ice on the floor (more like snow) and the wall coming up out of that pile of "snow"

Comment: And one more thing.
I'm knew into blender, so how exactly did you made that animation on the timeline?
I inserted the fluid effect but when I move frames, nothing happens

Comment: @DarkKool that animation comes from simulation baking (see the picture has a big "bake" button jut below of fluid type.

Comment: An error pops up: "No fluid inout objects in the scene"

Comment: @DarkKool if you used "quick fluid" it should not happen. That error should mean that you have no "fluid" or "inflow" objects in the simulation. The "quick fluid" setup creates a fluid object for the selected object (three pillars in the example above) and a domain around it. As for keeping some "ice" on the floor, you could fake it in any way you like, eg: with another shape or else... remember CG is often about faking if possible (cheap and quick)