# How to make a forest growth animation

Tags: particles

I bake an ABC animation file is a growing tree, it has a duration of 240 frames, my idea is to create a growing tree scene, particle birth time is random, I want every tree The animation start time is the particle's birth time, what should I do? Does animation node can be achieved? Can you provide a method?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73633/animate-branch-growth/

Comment: no .this effect https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoJi5bhJR5Y